# Can I express these conditionals with a single math formula?

Tags: javascript, math, formula, integer-division

Not sure of the best way to ask this question other than:

I'm writing a function that will accept a variable called 'x'.

```
function doIt(x){
  var y = someformula; //this is just a placeholder for the correct formula
  return y;
}
```

And here's what I expect returned:

```
if (x is between 0 and 9){ y = 0; }

if (x is between 10 and 19){ y = 32; }

if (x is between 20 and 29){ y = 64; }

if (x is between 30 and 39){ y = 96; }
```

and so on....

Any help is appreciated.

I'm doing it in JavaScript if it matters.

Comment: That's not really a "conditional".  That's a mapping between x and y.  `32*((x+10)/10)` or something similar.

Comment: How can it be JavaScript and language agnostic?

Comment: Are those conditions supposed to be consistent? You have `(x is between 10 and 19)` as well as `(x is between 19 and 29)`. Are those last two supposed to start at the next number up? (20 to 29 and 30 to 39, respectively).

Comment: @kbrimington - It's language agnostic because it's a mathematical formula, which could be applied to any language. It's JavaScript because the OP is working in JavaScript.

Comment: @S.Lott, right - just wasn't sure what to call it.

@kbrimington The general math formula is language agnostic. I wanted to be thorough and let others know I was using JavaScript in case something like Math.floor was needed due to JavaScript's integer division handling. And in fact, it was.

Comment: @Ryan - that was an error that I fixed right away, sorry bout that.

Comment: I agree with @kbrimington.  It's not language-agnostic.  The formula itself is trivial, and the exact implementation would clearly be different (and more concise) in C/C++/Java.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
return Math.floor(x/10) * 32;
```